# Confluent Kafka & docker-compose - error running example

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I'm trying to run the Confluent Platform all in one example using Docker Compose.  The example of using it with a single node is here:

http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/cp-docker-images/docs/quickstart.html#getting-started-with-docker-compose

The git repository with all the Docker images also has a load of other examples, including one which is supposed to provide the Control panel etc, as detailed here: http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.2/cp-docker-images/docs/intro.html#choosing-the-right-images.

Running the simple example works fine.  When I try to run the `cp-all-in-one` example ([link to GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/3.1.x/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml)), I get the following error on running `sudo docker-compose start` (`sudo docker-compose create` runs without error):

```
Starting zookeeper ... error
Starting broker ... error
Starting schema_registry ... error
Starting connect ... error
Starting control-center ... error

ERROR: for control-center  network cpallinone_default not found

ERROR: for zookeeper  network cpallinone_default not found

ERROR: for broker  network cpallinone_default not found

ERROR: for schema_registry  network cpallinone_default not found

ERROR: for connect  network cpallinone_default not found
No containers to start
```

There is no mention of `cpallinone_default` anywhere in the docs.  Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use docker-compose up. It will create the default network.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for more details

(in single-node, it used host network so you didn't had this problem)